# Javascript Show/Hide correct div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have a page with a drop down with 3 items:

```
<select name="orderOption" id="orderOption">
<option value="1">Item 1</option>
<option value="2">Item 2</option>
<option value="3">Item 3</option> 
</select>
```

Currently there is Javascript to show or hide a div with the appropriate class, based on that selection.

```
function orderOptionChanged() {
        var e = document.getElementById("orderOption");
        var orderOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        if (orderOption == "1") {
            $('.OrderOption1').show();
            $('.OrderOption2,.OrderOption3,').hide();
        }
```

This works fine for just the 3 of them, but now they want 25 of them. I need a way to select only the one option without having to write it all out. I've never worked with Javascript before, so this is all new to me.

Comment: Can you apply a single class to all of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var orderOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
$('*[class^="OrderOption"]').hide();
$('.OrderOption'+orderOption).show();
```

You could also assign a base class to all of them, and use that to call `.hide()`, as the current method has to go through ALL elements and check for their class.

`class^="OrderOption"` - This line selects all elements with a class "beginning with OrderOption".

`'.OrderOption'+orderOption` - Then we append the value from above onto another selector to select the appropriate `OrderOption`.

Comment: I'll go try this now.
If this works, it's going to be a lifesaver.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function orderOptionChanged() {
        var e = document.getElementById("orderOption");
        var orderOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;    
        $('#orderOption option').hide();
        $('.OrderOption'+orderOption).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Order your divs so that they appear in the same order as their corresponding option.  Give them all the same class.  Hide them all and then show the one that corresponds to the selected option:

```
$("#orderOption").change(function () {
    $(".orderOption").hide().eq(this.selectedIndex).show();
});
```

**Working Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mXc93/

Answer (score 0):

```
function orderOptionChanged() {
    var e = $("#orderOption");
    var orderOption = e.val();
    var option = $('.OrderOption'+orderOption);

    option.show();
    $('[class^=OrderOption]').not(option).hide();
}
```